# Как изменяется работоспособность компьютерного железа от времени?

Tags: железо

Предположим у меня есть ноутбук от 2008 года, на котором я работал, но который не разу не подвергался внешнему воздействию типа кофе, удара, прямых солнечных лучей и так далее. Зато ноутбук использовался для установки многочисленного пиратского софта и был перегружен программами.

Я удалил все программы, переустановил ОС и всё вроде работает. Теперь предположим, что точно такой же ноутбук у меня лежал с 2008 года в кладовке, на котором никто не работал вообще. Обзовём ноутбук который эксплуатировался как `Комп1`, а его близнец который не эксплуатировался `Комп2`.

Один мой знакомый говорил, что со временем, на уровне железа вылетают биты, отчего производительность компа падает, даже после переустановки ОС и всех программ. Другой мой знакомый говорил, что пятьдесят лет спустя комп работает также хорошо как и после продажи, и первый макинтош можно до сих пор юзать. И не какие биты нигде не вылетают.

**Вопрос:** Пусть мы установим и на `Комп1` и на `Комп2` много-много одинакового ПО. Они будут работать одинаково или `Комп1` всё же хуже? Вылетают ли биты в микросхеме во время эксплуатации? (внешние факторы не учитываем, только работа программ).

Очень интересны графики долговечности, если всё же падает работоспособность и ссылки на исследования.

Comment: Биты не вылетают, а гнутся. Скажите знакомому, чтобы учил матчасть.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev а что будет с ними, если они погнутся? (Я увы нуль в схемотехнике).

Comment: Одинаково. Насчет микросхем, если они вылетели, ноут обычно не завоится совсем.

Comment: @Axenow не согласен. Есть знаете ли код хэмминга, который скомпенсирует один неработающий бит.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Если один бит, то да. Но скорость работы компа - около миллиона операций в секунду. Если у вас ломается 1 бит в секунду, то это пофигу. Если у вас ломаются 100 бит - поверьте - будет ситуация, когда произойдет наложение и все немного упадет.

Comment: Для выпрямления гнутых битов приходится ставить катушки индуктивности — посмотрите, сколько их на материнской плате! И чем больше в системе гнутых битов, тем чаще им приходится проходить через катушки, что, естественно, замедляет прохождение сигнала и заставляет компьютер тормозить.

Comment: На современных Штеудах (Intel) используется терможвачка, которая со временем высыхает (вроде как). Причём она сильнее высыхает именно при нагреве (интенсивной работе процессора). Так что у многоработавшего компа может быть высохший термоинтерфейс, в результате чего при нагрузке будет троттлинг (понижение частоты при перегреве). Но это справедливо только для новых процев (и не всех моделей).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Один мой знакомый говорил, что со временем, на уровне железа вылетают
>   биты, отчего производительность компа падает, даже после переустановки
>   ОС и всех программ.

Биты не гнутся, не ржавеют, не плесневеют, не стачиваются. Или это такой толстый троллинг?

> Теперь предположим, что точно такой же ноутбук у меня лежал с 2008
>   года в кладовке, на котором никто не работал вообще.

Конечно, если комп не включался, то у него ресурс не использовался и теоретически он проработает дольше. Ну там, к примеру, у невключавшегося компа матрица может быть поярче. Но в целом, от количества ранее установленных программ производительность компов не изменяется. Ресурс вырабатывается, это да. Например, современные винчестеры рассчитаны на примерно 100000 часов работы. Это примерно 10 лет непрерывной работы. После этого вероятность отказа винчестера резко растет. Но пока комп не отказал (то есть пока у него винчестер не сломался, ОЗУ не сгорело, экран или подсветка экрана не перегорели, источник питания цел и все остальные подсистемы целы), то никакая предыдущая эксплуатация не снижает производительности компа. Достаточно переставить ОС и программы и все как новое.

> Пусть мы установим и на Комп1 и на Комп2 много-много одинакового ПО.
>   Они будут работать одинаково или Комп1 всё же хуже?

Одинаково.

> Вылетают ли биты в микросхеме во время эксплуатации? (внешние факторы
>   не учитываем, только работа программ).

Из-за работы программ производительность компов не падает. Но ресурс работы у компов есть и он связан со старением компонентов. И при эксплуатации во включенном состоянии старение компонентов (в общем случае) происходит быстрее. Старение некоторых частей (более энергетически нагруженных) происходит быстрее, чем старение других частей (менее энергетически нагруженных). Например, относительно быстрее стареют элементы блока питания, так как все энергия идет через них. Но это тоже зависит от компа. Можно сделать дефорсированную схему в которой элементы работают с недогрузкой, и такая схема проработает дольше обычной (но и будет немного дороже).

> Очень интересны графики долговечности, если всё же падает
>   работоспособность и ссылки на исследования.

В общем-то стеклотекстолит, из которого делают платы современной электроники, это пластик. И, как всякий пластик, на воздухе он деградирует со временем (медленно окисляется). Так что через 50 лет электрические параметры стеклотекстолита и вообще любого пластика меняются. А через 100-200 лет любой пластик вообще рассыпается в пыль. Но до этого времени ничего с ним не будет.

UPD1:

> но лучше если вы добавите ссылки на авторитетные истончики (как в
>   википедии), чтобы все могли информацию полученную от вас оперативно
>   проверить.

Боюсь, что таких ссылок дать невозможно. Никто так не ставит вопрос: "портятся ли компьютеры от интенсивной пересылки байтов". Просто потому, что от интенсивной пересылки байтов компьютеры не портятся. Компьютеры портятся от физических процессов старения материалов, от высыхания электролитических конденсаторов, от бросков питания в сети в конце концов. Если Вас интересует анализ физических причин надежности вычислительной техники, то это надо гуглить. Думаю, что такие работы есть отдельно по винчестерам, отдельно по материалам плат, отдельно по ЖК матрицам, отдельно по всем другим компонентам компьютера. Но это толстые специализированные работы, не предназначенные для популярного изложения. Скорее всего это внутрифирменные данные соответствующих производителей.

> Один мой знакомый говорил, что со временем, на уровне железа вылетают
>   биты, отчего производительность компа падает, даже после переустановки
>   ОС и всех программ. Другой мой знакомый говорил, что пятьдесят лет
>   спустя комп работает также хорошо как и после продажи, и первый
>   макинтош можно до сих пор юзать. И не какие биты нигде не вылетают.

Основной смысл моего ответа был в том, что первый Ваш знакомый был не прав, а второй был прав в том смысле, что если физически подсистемы компьютера исправны, то компьютер будет работать и через 50 лет так же, как он работал когда был новый.

Конечно, тут проскакивала информация что Эппл (к примеру) был пойман на намеренном программном снижении тактовой частоты своих старых телефонов. Если этот факт имеет место, то для неискушенного пользователя это будет выглядеть как "раньше эта игрушка у меня летала, а теперь тормозит, значит со временем биты хуже пересылаются". Но это не старение битов, а намеренный маркетинговый прием с целью стимулировать покупки новых моделей.

Comment: Ответ вроде полный, принимается, спасибо, но лучше если вы добавите ссылки на авторитетные истончики (как в википедии), чтобы все могли информацию полученную от вас оперативно проверить. Если вы этого не сделаете, не исключаю, что переприму ответ того, кто даст ссылки на АИ.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ простой и сложный одновременно, но в кратце разница конечно будет, никакие биты никуда не вылетают, конкретно в ноутбуках чаще всего забиваются пылью системы охлаждения из-за чего процессор включает тротлинг (т.е. искуственно замедляет себя чтобы снизить таким образом тепловыделение) и это выглядит как медленая работа, так-же HDD со временем начинают 'сыпатся' , т.е. там появляются повреждённые секторы которые сам HDD переназначает на имеющеися в запасе, но запас не вечен , к тому-же если сектор будет из запаса то это увеличит время получения данных. У нас есть сервера которые с 2008 года работают почти не выключаясь и никаких особых проблем с ними нету.